# Extracting a substring from a string created from a HTML

Tags: android, html, string, substring

I am trying to make an Android app to test a few things I learned and I'm quite stuck trying to take a substring from a string. I want to extract a substring from a text-only web page.

EDIT: used Jsoup, works very well. Now my problem is with the substring extraction. Actual code:

```
private class ScrapeNParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
            }
        }

        try {
            response = doc.body().text();
            response = response.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        }


        String tempStr = null;
        try {
            tempStr = response.substring(response.indexOf("--- Gold") + 18, response.indexOf("--- Gold") + 25);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (tempStr != null) {
            return tempStr;
        }
        else {
            return response;
        }

        //return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        textView.setText(result);
    }
}

public void updateQuotes(View view) {
    textView.setText("Loading...");
    ScrapeNParseURL task = new ScrapeNParseURL();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.kitco.com/texten/texten.html" });

}
```

The output is the substring between index 18 and 25, which leads me to think it is not finding the substrings.

Comment: try http://jsoup.org/ for such html scraping

Comment: There isn't any string that matches `--\n Gold` so you end up with a `NullPointerException`. What are you trying to get from the HTML exactly?

Comment: jsoup works great, thanks. Now the problem is another xD